NUnit TestFixture only on BaseTest class dotnet cli run
There are my test classes:
BaseTest.cs:
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Moq;
using NUnit.Framework;

[TestFixture]
public abstract class BaseTest
{
    protected Mock<IPatientRepository> PatientRepositoryMock = new();

    protected IConfiguration Configuration = null!;
    protected PasswordService PasswordService = null!;
    protected Mock<ICurrentUserService> CurrentUserMock = new();
    protected Mock<IUserRepository> UserRepositoryMock = new();
    protected Mock<IMapper> MapperMock = new();
    protected Mock<IPackageRepository> PackageRepositoryMock = new();



    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        CurrentUserMock = new Mock<ICurrentUserService>();
        PackageRepositoryMock = new Mock<IPackageRepository>();
        MapperMock = new Mock<IMapper>();
    }

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void OneTimeSetup()
    {
        PasswordService = new PasswordService();
        Configuration = ConfigurationsBuilder.Build();
    }
}

CreatePackageTests.cs
using Moq;
using NUnit.Framework;

public class CreatePackageTests : PackageTestsBase
{
    [Test]
    public void CreatePackage_DuplicateName_BadRequestException()
    {
        // Arrange
        var createPackageDto = new CreatePackageRequest
        {
            Name = "Basic Package"
        };

        PackageRepositoryMock.Setup(r => r.SaveChangesWithNameValidationAsync()).Throws<BadRequestException>(() =>
            throw new BadRequestException("Package with the same name already exists"));
        // Act & Assert
        var exception = Assert.ThrowsAsync<BadRequestException>(() => PackageService.CreateAsync(createPackageDto));
        Assert.That(exception?.Message, Is.EqualTo("Package with the same name already exists"));
    }
}

Here is the dotnet test result:
No test is available in {mydirectory}Application.UnitTests.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

I am using the same dotnet in Rider and in terminal:
rider:

terminal:

I am running test using Rider and rider running all test. But when I'm running from dotnet cli, dotnet cli does not found my CreatePackageTests I think because I haven't put the TestFixture attribute to CreatePackageTests.
Question: Is there any way to run all tests using dotnet cli?

Can you make sure that you're using the same .NET Cli and MBBuild versions in Rider and terminal?

Have you tried adding the TestFixture attribute to CreatePackageTests? If that works, I'd just go with that.

I have updated my question content. So: I am using same dotnet in rider and in terminal

Was not able to repro, dotnet test discovers all tests for me. What version of NUnit and .NET are you using? Please add a full [mre].

Same for me - all works with your setup.

The problem was with the NUnit3TestAdapter. I have updated the package. It works!
